# How to define the irrational domain or any other arbitrary domain?

Tags: evaluation, syntax, symbolic

I have found no way to define the domain of `Irrational` numbers.
I can easily define a test to see if a number is irrational by defining:

```
IrrationalQ[z_] := Element[z, Reals] && ! Element[z, Rationals]

IrrationalQ /@ Sqrt /@ Range[10]
```

> ```
> {False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, False, True}
> ```

My question is how can I define a domain that would work with `Element`, something like

```
Element[Sqrt[2], Irrationals]
```

I am aware that the documentation list possible domains as `Booleans, Complexes, Integers, Primes, Rationals, Reals`, but it is not clear to me if that list is exclusive or not.

Comment: @Ymareth your very small edit got accepted, in part by me (because I forgot that my vote alone was not enough). Of course it is nice to have a good title, but please do not suggest edits that are too small. You can read about this on [meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1023/4330)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another way, using [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagSetDelayed.html):

```
Irrationals /: Element[x_, Irrationals] := 
  Element[x, Reals] && ! Element[x, Rationals];

Element[Sqrt[2], Irrationals]
(*
  True
*)
```

This should work for elementary calculation.  However, I don't think there is way to fully incorporate `Irrationals` as a domain into *Mathematica* (e.g., into `Reduce[expr, vars, domain]` or `Solve`).  Note also that the predicate

```
Element[x, Reals] && ! Element[x, Rationals];
```

does not evaluate to `True` or `False` with approximate numbers (obviously, perhaps) and that algorithms that use numeric heuristics might be unreliable or simply be bypassed.

(I suspect that the domain is used in most cases to choose an algorithm.  The standard domains are what they are because so much work over the centuries has gone into developing algorithms for them.)

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there:

```
Unprotect[Element];
Element[x_, Irrationals] := Element[x, Reals] && ! Element[x, Rationals];

Sqrt[2] \[Element] Irrationals
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: I was not aware at all of the ability to `Unprotect`. Thanks so much!